# checking whether stored procedure inserted record

Tags: vb.net, stored-procedures

i have written stored procedure, where i am first checking whether the record for a particular is repeated more than thrice, if yes it should not insert new record, else it should insert the record in the database.

now in the if condition i have insert query, now i want to know how should i be able to know whether the insert query fired successfully or not. because if the IF statement fails it wont execute insert query, and what should i write in the else statement, so that i can come to know whether the insert query executed or not.

i am using VB.Net as a front end... please tell me the condition how i will be able to know the insert query fired or not.

Regards
Abbas Elecrticwala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can return a bit value depending on the insert. like

`create proc myproc`
`-- your variables here`
`as`
`begin`
`if (your condition )`
`begin`
`your insert query`
`select '1'` 
`end`
`else`
`begin`
`select '0'`
`end`
`end`

you can check the result in vb, and you will know depending on the bit value.

Comment: actually i am already using sqlcommand to execute the storedprocedure. is it possible that within executenonquery only i verify whether record inserted or not.

Comment: well if there is no update or delete query in your procedure, i mean if it just do inserts, then you can get the number of the rows affected by using executenonquery. if the result is -1, that means no insert or update or delete occured. here is the msdn page for more info http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: but if you decide to use a procedure like the one i wrote in my answer, you will have to use executescalar. if the result is 1, then insert occured, if its 0, no insert.